# Populating one column based on contents of another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to pull email addresses from one column and put them in another column. The only thing I am struggling with at the moment is that this needs to be done based on whether the data in two other columns is the same.

I have the names of the companies in one column and the email addresses in the next. I am copying in the company names from a separate spreadsheet where it is not in the same order. I would like to be able to populate Column A with the email addresses based on if the company name is the same but I'm currently struggling to work out how this is possible.

[Here is a link as to an example of what I mean.](https://docs.google.com/a/pleasance.co.uk/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtIvBi5LprN7dFFJeWdnTkp5NHBIRXRIbmtNbk5sclE#gid=0)

I think I am way, way off with my code at the moment but here is what I have.

```
function pullEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;   var numRows = 2;

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)   
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var showname1 = row[1];
    var showname2 = row[3];
    var values1 = sheet.getRange("B2:B100").getValues();
    var values2 = sheet.getRange("D2:D100").getValues();

    if (showname1=showname2){
      sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(sheet.getRange("E2").getValues());     
    }     
  } 
}
```

Which doesn't do what I need. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated! A very basic user at the moment so still sort of working in the dark!

Answer (score 3):

Just a small mistake... you need the equality operator "==" to compare values:

```
if (showname1 == showname2)
```

Attention: When iterating over arrays, it is also not recommended to use the `for (... in ...)` construct, as this will also access enumerable properties of the object, and not just the iterable data array. Instead, when use `for (start, limit, increment)` Read more: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)